# Affine Cover of $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-schemes, projective-varieties

I have a question in understanding Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry Corollary 2.3, Ch. 1. It says that any projective variety $Y\subset{\mathbb{P}}^n$ is covered by the open sets $Y\cap U_i$ (this part is clear) and that each $Y\cap U_i$ is homeomorphic to an affine variety via $\varphi_i$.

Definitions used: $U_i$ is defined as the set of all points in $\mathbb{P}^n$ with the i-th component non-zero and $\varphi_i$ is the (homeomorphic) map from $U_i$ to the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ given by $[a_0,...,a_n] \mapsto (a_1/a_i,...,a_n/a_i)$. A variety is always meant to be an irreducible algebraic subset.

Here are my questions concerning the second part of the corollary:

1) How is the intersection of $Y\cap U_i\cong Y\cap \mathbb{A}^n$ calculated? Does one use the (disjoint) open covering $\mathbb{P}^n=\bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathbb{A}^{n-i}$ and hence $Y\cap \mathbb{A}^n$ is the set of all $\mathbb{A}^n$-components of $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^n$?

2) How can one show that $Y\cap U_i\cong Y\cap \mathbb{A}^n$ is again irreducible? In which topology shall it be closed?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The ideal of the intersection $Y\cap U_i$ is calculated by "dehomogenizing," setting $x_i$ equal to $1$. The open cover you mention is not disjoint.

2.If $Y\cap U_i$ were reducible, then it would be the union of proper closed subsets. Taking closures in $\mathbb P^n$ would make $Y$ reducible. The topology is the Zariski topology on $U_i\cong \mathbb A^n$, which is also the subspace topology.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer! I just wonder why above mentioned open cover is not disjoint. I used $U_i$ as above and $H_i$ being the subset of all elements in $P^n$ with the i-th component zero. Then the union $P^n=U_0\cup H_0$ is cleary disjoint. Using the isomorphisms $U_i\cong A^n$ and $H_i\cong P^{n-1}$ and successive application gives the isomorphism $P^n=U_0\cup H_0\cong A^n\cup P^{n-1}\cong A^n\cup A^{n-1}\cup H_1\cong A^n\cup A^{n-1}\cup P^{n-2}\cong...$.

Comment: Glad to help! Each H_i is disjoint from its corresponding U_i, but the U_i are not disjoint from one another. For instance, in P^2 (1,1,1) is in all three U_i.

Comment: Ok, I get your point! Thanks a lot.