# Hartshorne, Corollary 2.3 question, which topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I have a question about Corollary 2.3 (p. 11) of Hartshorne's algebraic geometry book.  Let
$$
D(x_i)= \{[z_0, \ldots, z_n]\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1} \mid z_i \neq 0\} \subset\mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{C}) \, .
$$

Notice $\bigcup_{i=0}^n D(x_i) = \mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Provided $Y$ a closed projective variety, he mentions a homeomorphism between (left) $Y \cap D(x_i)$ and (right) "an affine variety" $\phi_i |_Y(Y \cap D(x_i))$, where $\phi_i$ is a homeomorphism between D($x_i$) and $\mathbb{A}^n$.

My question is simple; what are the topologies for which we have a homeomorphism? He mentions an "induced topology". Can we just take the Zariski topology for both (right) and (left)?

See also [this previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181061/affine-cover-of-pn).

Comment: By the induced topology, he just means the subspace (or relative topology).    Let $V = Y \cap D(x_i)$.  Then $V \subseteq Y$, so we can equip it with the subspace topology, defining the open sets of $V$ to be sets of the form $W \cap V$ where $W$ is an open subset of $Y$.

Comment: I posted an answer: let me know if it cleared up your confusion.

Comment: Do we still have a homeomorphism between $D(x_i)$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ if we use the subspace topology of $D(x_i)$ w.r.t. the quotient topology induced by the quotient map q: $\mathbb{C}^n-{0} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{C})$ and the usual topology on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Is there a counter example to using a finer topology than the Zariski topology?

Answer (score 1):

To understand the statement of the corollary, let's consider the the preceding proposition.  For $i = 0, 1, \ldots, n$, Hartshorne defines the map
\begin{align*}
\varphi_i : U_i &\to \mathbf{A}^n\\
[a_0 : a_1 : \cdots : a_n] &\mapsto \left(\frac{a_0}{a_i}, \ldots, \widehat{\frac{a_i}{a_i}}, \ldots, \frac{a_n}{a_i}  \right)
\end{align*}
where the hat indicates that $a_i/a_i$ is omitted.  (Here $U_i = D(x_i)$.)  $\mathbf{P}^n$ is given the usual (homogeneous) Zariski topology, and $U_i \subseteq \mathbf{P}^n$ is given what Hartshorne calls the induced topology, but what I like to call the subspace or relative topology: we define the open sets of $U_i$ to be those of the form $V \cap U_i$ where $V$ is an open subset of $\mathbf{P}^n$.

**Proposition 2.2.** *The map $\varphi_i$ is a homeomorphism of $U_i$ with its induced topology to $\mathbf{A}^n$ with its Zariski topology.*

Corollary 2.3 follows easily from this proposition.  Given a closed projective variety $Y \subseteq \mathbf{P}^n$, consider the restrictions of the above maps $\varphi_i|_Y: Y \to \mathbf{A}^n$.  In the corollary, Hartshorne claims that $\varphi_i|_Y(Y \cap U_i) \subseteq \mathbf{A}^n$ is an affine variety (again, equipped with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbf{A}^n$) and
$$
\varphi_i: Y \cap U_i \overset{\sim}{\longrightarrow} \varphi_i|_Y(Y \cap U_i)
$$
is a homeomorphism.

Comment: just to clarify, so $\phi_i |_Y (Y \cap U_i)$is closed in the zariski topology? and we give the subspace topology inherited from the zariski topology to both domain and codomain of $\phi_i |_Y$?

Comment: Yes, $Y \cap U_i$ is given the subspace topology induced by the (homogeneous) Zariski topology on $\mathbf{P}^n$ and $\varphi_i|_Y(Y \cap U_i)$ is given the subspace topology induced by the Zariski topology on $\mathbf{A}^n$.  In the proof of Prop. 2.2, Hartshorne shows that the image is closed.  Basically, $Y$ is defined by homogeneous polynomials: $\varphi_i(Y \cap U_i)$ will be the vanishing set of the dehomogenization of those polynomials with respect to $x_i$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Could you elaborate on how Corollary 2.3 follows easily from the Proposition? This is not easy for me.

Comment: @user46372819 Which part of the corollary is unclear to you?

Comment: @ViktorVaughn That the $Y \cap U_i$ are homeomorphic to affine varieties via the mapping $\varphi_i$. How is $\varphi_i(Y \cap U_i)$ an affine variety?

Comment: @ViktorVaughn I think this may be equivalent to showing that $Y \cap U_i$ is irreducible closed subset of $U_i$.

Comment: @user46372819 Regarding your second comment: since $Y$ is closed in $\mathbb{P}^n$, then $Y \cap U_i$ is closed in $U_i$ by the definition of the subspace topology. And a nonempty open subset of an irreducible space is irreducible; see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Open_Set_of_Irreducible_Space_is_Irreducible).

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Right. That shows $Y \cap U_i$ is an irreducible subset of $Y$. But we want to show that $Y \cap U_i$ is irreducible subset of $U_i$.

Comment: @user46372819 Irreducibility is an intrinsic notion. It depends only on the topological space itself, not any ambient space.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn I don’t understand how. To show $Y \cap U_i$ is irreducible, we would use the fact that it is open in $Y$. How then would this imply that it is irreducible in $U_i$?

Comment: @user46372819 What is your definition of irreducible? Mine is: a topological space $X$ is irreducible if it cannot be written as a union $X = W_1 \cup W_2$ of two proper closed subsets $W_1, W_2$ of $X$. You’ll note that there is no reference to any ambient space—that’s what I mean by irreducibility being intrinsic. It doesn't really make sense to say that something is irreducible in something else, as irreducibility is not a relative notion. In the same way, you wouldn't say $Y$ is compact in $X$, because compactness is an intrinsic property.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Gotcha. That helped. Thanks.